# I need to iterate through 2 arrays in ruby on rails.. I know zip function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let me show you the code first..
in my controller I have 2 arrays =

```
   @confessions = Confession.where(amitian_id: @amitian.ids).order('created_at DESC') if amitian_signed_in?
   @anonyconfess = Confession.where(amitian_id: @anonymous.ids).order('created_at DESC')
```

so 2 arrays @confessions and @anonyconfess... what I want is to iterate through both the arrays at the same time and post the confessions .. here is my view

```
    -@anonyconfess.each do |c|
                #code       
                %br
    -@confessions.each do |c|
                #code               
                %br
```

I want to do this at the same time rather than this 2 separate iterations...
should I use @confessions.zip(@anonymous)
knowing that array size of both are different I don't think zip is a good approach or is it ?

Comment: Should the list be one after the others, or mixed?

Comment: I think you have, in fact, two ActiveRecord::Relation objects. This is what this `#where` method returns. You may just write something like `@all_confessions = @anonyconfess + @confessions`. See this: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/05/adding-activerecord-relations.html

Comment: @Alaap please help us understand this question better by answering Eric's question above.

Comment: @jagdeepSingh I wanted mixed up results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine both queries into one:

```
ids = @anonymous.ids
ids.concat(@amitian.ids) if amitian_signed_in?
@confessions = Confession.where(amitian_id: ids).order('created_at DESC')
```

And in your view:

```
- @confessions.each do |c|
  #code               
  %br
```

Answer (score 3):

## Each-each

If you want them one after the other :

```
-[@anonyconfess, @confessions].each do |confess|
  -confess.each do |c|
    #code
    %br
```

## Set union

Good tip from @JagdeepSingh :

```
  -(@anonyconfess | @confessions).each do |c|
    #code
    %br
```

## zip

If you want them mixed, `zip` should be the right tool, you'd just need to make sure the first array is longer than the second one :

```
array_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array_2 = %w(a b c)

array_1.zip(array_2).each do |x, y|
  p x
  p y
  puts
end
# 1
# "a"

# 2
# "b"

# 3
# "c"

# 4
# nil

# 5
# nil

array_2.zip(array_1).each do |y, x|
  p x
  p y
  puts
end
# 1
# "a"

# 2
# "b"

# 3
# "c"
```

NOTE: @Stefan's answer is better anyway :)

Comment: You could also use `(@anonyconfess + @confessions).each` to avoid the inner `each`.

Comment: point is if I use zip ... few posts will never show due to the way zip works ryt ?

Comment: Or `(@anonyconfess | @confessions).each` to avoid possibility of any duplicate entry.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am really mistaken, you don't have two arrays, but two `ActiveRecord::Relation` instances. But don't worry, they really work like arrays most of the time and you may just write something like

```
@all_confessions = @anonyconfess + @confessions
```

and then in your view use

```
-@all_confessions.each do |confess|
          #code
          %br
```

Please refer to [this article](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/05/adding-activerecord-relations.html) here to learn more about this.

This will show the posts in the same order you would have with

```
-@anonyconfess.each do |c|
             #code      
             %br
-@confessions.each do |c|
             #code              
             %br
```

In other words, `@anonyconfess` will appear first and then `@confessions`.

If you want then to really 'mix', maybe you should consider one of the other answers.

Comment: will this produce a mixed up array that will include all the elements ?

Comment: Yes, but not mixing then in a certain order. I'll edit the question to elaborate more.

Comment: I tried this is just adding one array elements in the end of other array.. this is a good approach for ordered results but I want random..

Comment: @AlaapDhall, I just edited this answer to explain more. This answer does exactly what you said you need. It is exactly what you would have with the code you posted and I reproduced in the answer now.

Comment: adding them explicitily or defining 2 diff .each gives similar result

Comment: Yes. @Stephan's answer seems to suit better to what you need.

Comment: yes, it did Thank you for your time and efforts I appreciate :)